# Show that $A\times B=B\times A$ if and only if $A=B.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

Could you tell me if this all right. And how is the best way to go backwards? it is by cases? 
Thanks. 
Sorry is not in latex, but I´m just learning.

Comment: I'm getting lost, what are $A$ and $B$, are they sets both contained in some larger set?

Comment: Counterexample: $A$ is the empty set, $B$ is any other set; then $A\ne B$ but $A\times B=B\times A.$

Comment: @Mathematical Any two sets are contained in some larger set, namely $A\cup B$.

Comment: There's a missing hypothesis for the backwards direction. Once you know what the hypothesis is, you should be able to solve the exercise : you must assume $A,B\neq \emptyset$. Edit : bof was quicker

Comment: I presume A and B are sets.  What is the definition of $\times$?

Comment: Yes, they are sets. And X works for anything, should be general.

Answer (score 3):

This is not quite true: If $A=\varnothing$ then $A\times B = \varnothing = B\times A$ even if $B\ne\varnothing.$

However we can deal with the case where $A\ne \varnothing\ne B.$

If $A\ne B$ then something is a member of one of these sets but not of the other. So suppose $x\in A$ and $x\notin B.$ And let $y$ be some member of $B.$ Then $(x,y)\in A\times B$ but $(x,y)\notin B\times A.$

And the same sort of argument deals with the case in which $B$ has some member that is not a member of $A.$

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you need $A$ and $B$ both to be inhabited, or else $A \times B$ and $B \times A$ are both empty.

Here's a direct proof that $A=B$, without using contradiction.

First, fix some $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.

To prove $A = B$, we'll prove $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$.

- Take $x \in A$. Then $(x,b) \in A \times B$, so $(x,b) \in B \times A$, and so $x \in B$. This proves $A \subseteq B$.
- Take $x \in B$. Then $(a,x) \in A \times B$, so $(a,x) \in B \times A$, and so $x \in A$. This proves $B \subseteq A$.

And we're done!